# Fortify Rescan issues

Tags: fortify, fortify-source

Fortify Real world scenario issue:

The real issues I consistently having is not in actual remediation of fortify issues, but rather in being reliably suppressed any finding that are determined to be false-positives. I can suppress them in the report - that I confident about that, but that still doesn't prevent the same issues from being identified in a subsequent scan of the code. And that, in turn, involves significant time on my part to suppress them EVERYtime we run a scan.

So I may be deploying changes to the same code files several times throughout the year. so every time I need to spend some significant time to remove false positive on the code.

My flow: -

scan --> identify fasle positive --> supress in report --> deploy --> again make changes --> scan --> identify fasle positive -->supress in report --> deploy.  this process repeats..

Is there any way to overcome these kinds of repeated problems so that will help me a lot.

Answer (score 1):

The problem I think you're experiencing requires merging the FPR (Fortify Project Report). If you perform analysis in one FPR and then do another scan, there needs to be a merge to bring the previous analysis forward. Some of the Fortify products do this automatically. Software Security Center, VS Studio Plugin, and Eclipse Plugin automatically merge the new FPR with the old FPR. You can also manually merge the FPR file using Audit Work Bench (Its under Tools>Merge Audit Projects) or you can use the command line using the FPR Utility. The command would be:

```
FPRUtility -merge -project <primary.fpr> -source <secondary.fpr> -f <output.fpr>
```